# Committing to a SharedPreferences Variable

Tags: android

I am trying to understand when is the value added to a SharedPreferences actually committed. Upon executing the code below, the initial value of the variable valCount is set to 0, to which 1 is then added with valCount+1. Meanwhile, the log.e method initially returns 0 (which is executed after the valCount+1 code). Only upon calling this code a second time will the value of the variable valCount be displayed as having a value of 1 when calling the log.e method.

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    valCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("valCount", 0);
    editor.putInt("valCount", valCount+1);
    editor.apply();
    Log.e("valCount", valCount+"");
```

Comment: Bro, you get the value before you change it, you need to get the value again, after it changes. Basically you need to call:
 valCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("valCount", 0);
An second time after the call of putInt(...).

Comment: Thank you Pedro.

Comment: You welcome bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Android DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()) for `apply`:

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent
>   storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory
>   SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to
>   disk and you won't be notified of any failures.

So, as `apply()` saves your data async  you don't see those changes right away on the disk. If you'd like to save it synchronously you should use `commit`.

By the way, to see the difference you should call `sharedPreferences.getInt("valCount", 0)` in your `Log` rather than `valCount`. `valCount` still references the object from the first call of `sharedPreferences.getInt("valCount", 0)` (your second line).

Comment: Thank you Anatolii.